# How can I redirect to the log in page when I press the log out button

Tags: php

When I'm using the following code I get a blank page

```
  <form action="login.php ">
    <input type="submit" name="log out" value="Log Out">
```

Comment: Is this all the code you have? What have you established your login with. Cookies? Session?

Comment: Please provide some more description.Provide your proper code.

Comment: <form action="data.php" method="POST">
 UserName <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"><br>
 
 PassWord <input type="password" name="password"><br>
 
 Remember Me <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="remember"><br>
 
 <input type="submit" name="login" value="LogIn"> this is my login page coding and i m creating session for it

Comment: Please provide code in answer, as there is no formatting in comments.

Comment: Why are you using PHP. You can do all of it in old style html. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use
`header("location:login.php");`
that will automatically redirect you on that page

Comment: He is not using session at all. It seems. We can not provide a solution because it is turning out to be complex :)

Answer (score 1):

first of all you have to use sessions if you use session then  print following code

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION["name"]);
header("Location:index.php");
?>
```

if you are not using session then simply use redirect in php

1.create logout.php page code

```
<?php
    header("Location:index.php");
    ?>
```

2.after that

```
<form action=logout.php method=post>
    <input type="submit" name="log out" value="Log Out">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code there was no closing tag for form (`</form>`).May be that is making issue..
Also always add all the attributes to your html elements like 'name'.You missed form name. this is a good practice.

Try this

```
<form name="formname" action="data.php" method="POST"> 
UserName <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"><br> 
PassWord <input type="password" name="password"><br> 
Remember Me <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="remember"><br> 
<input type="submit" name="login" value="LogIn"> 
</form>
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: On submiting r u redirected to data.php?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<button type="button" onclick="document.location='login_page.php'">Login Page</button>
```

It will redirect you when the button clicked

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a `session` variable. And `unset` it. And do redirect to any page you want.

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION["nome"]);  // where $_SESSION["nome"] is your own variable. if you do not have one use only this as follow **session_unset();**
header("Location: homepage.php");
```

Edited: Always use Session variable. Because it gets set at server side and as an admin, you have more control over it.

Comment: can I use `session_destroy()`?